# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unauthorized I am getting this error while working with mailchimp API. please help me out

Tags: node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

mailchimp.setConfig({
apikey: "5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9",
server: "usXX"
});

async function run() {

var response = await mailchimp.ping.get();

console.log(response);
}

run();

[please refer to the error image => "this is the error it's showing"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kdxl.png)

Comment: The unhandled rejection warning comes from the missing try/catch block in your async function. Add a try/catch or remove the async/await and use the then/catch methods.

Comment: Need to have desc + put the code inside ```